# Generic method which works with RDD and Seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-cats

I would like to write a method which would accept `RDD` and `Seq` without having to duplicate my code.

```
def myMethod[F[_]](input: F[InputClass]): F[OutputClass] = {
    // do something here like
    input.map{ i => 
       // transformed input OutputClass
    }
}
```

`F` could be `Seq` or `RDD` since they both have the method `map` implemented.

For more unique method like `count` or `cache` can I make the `Seq` do nothing for `cache` and use `length` for `count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a [Type Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class).
If you only need `map` and `flatMap` methods, I would recommend you to use a **Monad** *(maybe the [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monad.html) one)* and provide a the implementation for `RDD`.

Now, if you want more methods, you can implement your own Type Class.

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait DataCollection[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](col: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
  def cache[A](col: F[A]): F[A]
  def count[A](col: F[A]): Long
}

object DataCollection { 
  implicit val RddDataCollection: DataCollection[RDD] = new DataCollection[RDD] {
    override def map[A, B](rdd: RDD[A])(f: A => B): RDD[B] = rdd.map(f)
    override def cache[A](rdd: RDD[A]): RDD[A] = rdd.cache()
    override def count[A](rdd: RDD[A]): Long = rdd.count()
  }

  implicit val SeqDataCollection: DataCollection[Seq] = new DataCollection[Seq] {
    override def map[A, B](seq: Seq[A])(f: A => B): Seq[B] = seq.map(f)
    override def cache[A](seq: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = seq
    override def count[A](seq: Seq[A]): Long = seq.length
  }

  implicit class Ops[F[_], A](val col: F[A]) extends AnyVal {
    @inline
    def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit DC: DataCollection[F]): F[B] = DC.map(col)(f)

    @inline
    def cache()(implicit DC: DataCollection[F]): F[A] = DC.cache(col)

    @inline
    def count()(implicit DC: DataCollection[F]): Long = DC.count(col)
  }
}

def myGenericMethod[F[_]: DataCollection, T](col: F[T]): Long = {
  import DataCollection.Ops
  col.map(x => x).cache().count()
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Here is your solution running on Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8ardI5XtRHOgUMbBu7Y8uw